# How to set the value of a property to null using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to set the value of **LastName** to null using reflection.

```
public void SetPropertyValueToNull(Type t)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty("LastName");
    prop.SetValue(t, null, null);
}
```

I am passing **typeof(User)** as the parameter from another class where **User** is a model class which has **LastName** as one of the properties.
It gives me **Object does not match target type** error.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Where is the object instance on which you want to set the property to null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It gives me Object does not match target type error.

The first parameter of the `SetValue` method is the object instance on which you want to set the property value.

You are passing `t` itself as the first parameter which is of type `Type`. You should instead pass an object that has a type equal to `t`, e.g. `User` in your specific case.

You should change your method to accept an object instance instead of a `Type` and you can use it to get its type, get the property and then set its value.

So your method should look something like this:

```
public void SetPropertyValueToNull(object instance)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = instance.GetType().GetProperty("LastName");
    prop.SetValue(instance, null, null); //We need this overload for .NET < 4.5
}
```

This method will work for any object that has a writable property named `LastName`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the object instance, other wise what is it setting to null